# How to prove code correctness lemmas with the "undefined" constant

Tags: code-generation, isabelle

Given I have a very simple definition for code generation. It is only defined for certain cases and throws a runtime exception otherwise.

```
definition "blubb a = (if P a then True else undefined)"
```

Now I want to show `blubb` correct. The case in which the exception is thrown should be ignored (from my point of view, not the mathematical point of view). However, I end up with a subgoal that assumes that some arbitrary value `X` is `undefined`. The following lemma is more or less equivalent to the subgoal. I want to show `False` as I want to ignore the case in which the exception is thrown (i.e., `undefined` is returned).

```
lemma "X = undefined ⟹ False"
```

This is not provable.

```
  try

Nitpick found a counterexample for card 'a = 1:
 Free variable:
  X = a1
```

What is the best way to show correctness of functions that might throw exceptions or deal with `undefined`?
This relates to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316313/generating-code-from-locales-without-interpretation) question.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by showing `blubb` correct? For me that would just be `P a ==> blubb`, which is trivial with the given definition.

Comment: `blubb` is just an example. For example, `blubb a` could be an efficient algorithm to calculate `distinct a` faster than the default implementation, but is just defined for sorted lists (bad example) ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`undefined` is a constant in Isabelle which you don't know anything about. In particular, you can not in general prove that `X ≠ undefined`.

If you want to write functions that are only valid for certain inputs, you might consider using the `'a option` type, as follows:

```
definition "blubb a ≡ (if P a then Some True else None)"
```

and then in your proofs assume that `blubb a` is defined as follows:

```
lemma "∃x. blubb a = Some x ⟹ Q (blubb a)"
  ...
```

or simply:

```
lemma "a ∈ dom blubb ⟹ Q (blubb a)"
  ...
```

The value of `blubb a` can then be extracted using `the (blubb a)`.

Comment: There are cases where it is possible to show that something **is** equal to `undefined`. E.g., above `~ P a ==> blubb a = undefined` would work. Showing that some `X` is **not** equal to `undefined` will never work (since `undefined` is an arbitrary inhabitant of the type of `X`, and thus **could** indeed be `X`; this kind of construction works, since every type in `HOL` is inhabited).

Comment: What if I'm really interested in the code generation and do not want an option type but an exception thrown instead of `None`?

Comment: Why not just get the value of the option in your code? That would throw an exception if it is `None`.